# How to delete a file using delete_files function of File Helper

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to delete a file in codeigniter.
I want to use `delete_files` function, but it returns `false` !

```
    $this->load->helper("file");
    return delete_files(base_url().'application/cache/'.'blade-'.$cache_path);
```

Why it is returning false instead of deleting files.

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
    return unlink(APPPATH.'cache/'.'blade-'.$cache_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$this->load->helper('file');
return delete_files(FCPATH.'application/cache/'.'blade-'.$cache_path);
```

Codeigniter [delete_files](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html#delete_files) function will delete files inside a directory and it returns true or false.

> Returns:TRUE on success, FALSE in case of an error

You  getting False means you have error.

Possible reasons for errors

- Folder does not exists.
- Folder path is not valid
- Does not have proper permission

> The files must be writable or owned by the system in order to be
>   deleted.

For your case `base_url().'application/cache/'.'blade-'.$cache_path` is not a valid folder path.you added `base_url` before your folder name which will make the folder name like an URL. But It should be folder path.

Use [`FCPATH`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=fcpath#constants) instead of `base_url`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the path to the folder delete like

```
$this->load->helper('file');
return delete_files(APPPATH.'cache/'.'blade-'.$cache_path);
```

you don´t need to writte the url, coz the APPPATH places the pointer on the folder application, then you only specify in what subfolder you want to delete the file